# Error after installing Tridion Reference Implementation: cd_dynamic_conf no valid localizations active

Tags: dxa

I'm getting the following web application error when i try to browse to the Reference Implementation website:

> No valid localizations are active for this site.  Check the site log,
>   and that you have the right localization IDs configured in
>   cd_dynamic_conf.xml

I checked the config file and checked the id of the website which is correct.

```
<Publications>
    <Publication Id="81">
        <Host Domain="localhost" Port="80" Protocol="http" Path=""/>
    </Publication>
</Publications>
```

Not really sure what to do next. There is nothing in the site log (except for the error I pasted) and nothing in the cd_core.log.

**Stack trace**

> [Exception: No valid localizations are active for this site. Check the site log, and that you have the right localization IDs configured in cd_dynamic_conf.xml]
>   Sdl.Web.Common.Configuration.SiteConfiguration.Load(String
>   applicationRoot) +7136
>   Sdl.Web.Common.Configuration.SiteConfiguration.Refresh() +296
>   Sdl.Web.Site.MvcApplication.Application_Start() +343
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): No valid localizations are active for
>   this site. Check the site log, and that you have the right
>   localization IDs configured in cd_dynamic_conf.xml]
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext
>   context, HttpApplication app) +12962661
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +175
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state,
>   MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +304
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context) +404
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr
>   appContext) +475
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): No valid localizations are active for
>   this site. Check the site log, and that you have the right
>   localization IDs configured in cd_dynamic_conf.xml]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +12979668
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
>   +159    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +12819261

In my site.log when on Debug mode:

> 2014-10-21 12:18:42,364 [1] DEBUG - Binary with url /system/_all.json not found 2014-10-21 12:18:42,422
>
> [1] DEBUG - Binary with url /version.json not found 2014-10-21 12:18:42,422
>
> [1] DEBUG - Loading config for localization : '' 2014-10-21 12:18:42,424 [1] WARN  - Localization configuration bootstrap file:
>   C:\Websites\Preview\ASP.NET\refimp\BinaryData\system\config_all.json does not exist - skipping this localization 2014-10-21 12:18:42,425
>
> [1] DEBUG - MediaUrlRegex: ^/favicon.ico 2014-10-21 12:18:42,426
>
> [1] ERROR - No valid localizations are active for this site. Check the  site log, and that you have the right localization IDs configured in cd_dynamic_conf.xml

Comment: Set your log level to DEBUG in /Log.config and /conf/logback.xml - this should show a bit more info about what is happening. Also check if any files are written into the /BinaryData folder

Comment: Could you ensure that port 80 is available and is not in use by any other active site?

Comment: Port 80 is definitely in use by like 15 other sites, it's the PE :) But this shouldn't matter right?

Comment: @Will, there is no BinaryData folder... See Debug log in edited post...

Comment: This error is typically a sign that the publication ID is incorrect - at least, I've seen it a few times because of this.

Comment: This so weird, because it is really the correct ID. But I'll try to reinstall the whole package again. Just to see if it might work after that. I'll keep you posted.

Answer (score 5):

So, the answer to the question was:
 - the deployer was deploying to filesystem for pages and binaries instead of broker database.

After changing this the website loaded.

Special thanks to Will as he found out what was wrong!

Comment: Putting the CD logging to debug showed that while it could find the binary meta, it could not load the binary content

Answer (score 1):

From the information in the logs, it seems that it cannot find published content for your site. This can be due to:

- Publishing not being completed successfully - check that the _System/Publish Settings page is published OK
- Problems connecting to the broker database - check the cd logs for any issues, which might include licensing and broker DB connection problems

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I'm not sure why it isn't working. DB connection is fine, there are items published to it, it's just not fetching the data, I guess. I'll try a reinstall. If I have anything new i'll post it here!