# Error setting up DXA Website

Tags: dxa

I am getting the below error while setting up a DXA web site and browsing it.

> No valid localizations are active for this site. Check the site log,
>   and that you have the right localization IDs configured in
>   cd_dynamic_conf.xml

I've checked the "cd_dynamic_conf.xml" and it has proper configuration.Also the logs don't suggest anything related. As answered [here](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/8194/error-after-installing-tridion-reference-implementation-cd-dynamic-conf-no-vali) the same question, My binaries are set to publish to the Broker Database and are available in broker but I am still having the issue.

Comment: how are you accessing the site? localhost? the hostname and port need to match in the cd_dynamic_conf.xml file. Also the publication id. Did you publish the settings too?

Comment: Yeah, I've checked all the things you mentioned and published the settings.

Comment: Have you checked the logs? What do they say?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With the help of [Harald](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/users/242/harald-hoffelinck), I figured out the issue.

So when your `DXA` Web Application starts and the first Web Request is made, `DXA` creates a Directory called "BinaryData" in the root of you application to hold the binaries used on the page.

So to create it, your Website Application Pool's Identity User Account (in my case Network Service) must have write permissions on Websites Root Folder. I was missing those permissions on the Root Folder of my Website, assigning the right permissions solves the issue.