# Reference Implementation installation. No valid localizations are active for this site

Tags: 2013, dxa, iis-and-asp.net

I am trying to install reference implementation on Windows server 2008. after running the powershelll script of web-application i end up with the error 500.19. Then i commented the code between < staticContent > tags in web.config file in tridion. since then i am getting the below issue.

**No valid localizations are active for this site. Check the site log, and that you have the right localization IDs configured in cd_dynamic_conf.xml**

**Description:**An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

**Exception Details:**System.Exception: No valid localizations are active for this site. Check the site log, and that you have the right localization IDs configured in cd_dynamic_conf.xml

**Source Error:**
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

[**Exception:**No valid localizations are active for this site. Check the site log, and that you have the right localization IDs configured in cd_dynamic_conf.xml]
   Sdl.Web.Common.Configuration.SiteConfiguration.Load(String applicationRoot) +7136
   Sdl.Web.Common.Configuration.SiteConfiguration.Refresh() +293
   Sdl.Web.Site.MvcApplication.Application_Start() +343
[**HttpException (0x80004005):** No valid localizations are active for this site. Check the site log, and that you have the right localization IDs configured in cd_dynamic_conf.xml]
System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +12601645
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +175
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +304
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +404
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +475
[**HttpException (0x80004005):** No valid localizations are active for this site. Check the site log, and that you have the right localization IDs configured in cd_dynamic_conf.xml]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +12618692
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +159
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +12458309

**Version Information:** Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34249

Please help me with this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/8194/error-after-installing-tridion-reference-implementation-cd-dynamic-conf-no-vali

Comment: After editing log config to debug mode I found this error  in the site log file:
 [13] DEBUG - Loading config for localization : ''
2015-08-03 13:16:40,469 [13] WARN  - Localization configuration bootstrap file: D:\APPS\Tridion\DataStore\BinaryData\system\config\_all.json does not exist - skipping this localization
2015-08-03 13:16:40,469 [13] DEBUG - MediaUrlRegex: ^/favicon.ico
2015-08-03 13:16:40,469 [13] ERROR - No valid localizations are active for this site. Check the site log, and that you have the right localization IDs configured in cd_dynamic_conf.xml

Comment: Did you publish the site?

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this error before and I've found that it's usually caused by a missing resource resource and/or bad configuration.

Is your storage configured to save pages to a filesystem? This was the cause of the problem in [this](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/8194/error-after-installing-tridion-reference-implementation-cd-dynamic-conf-no-vali) previous question (same error message).

When Tridion deploys content to a target it can place it in different places depending on your storage configuration. On your deployer, you need to inspect the configuration file cd_storage_conf.xml and check that pages are being stored in a database and not on the filesystem. You also need to check that this configuration is matching in your web application. See [Configuring content storage](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-D7B8D088-0AD3-4652-9A61-BC86B25D04CE) in the online documentation for more information.

Comment: What do you mean by "storage configure to save pages in a filesystem?" i am new to Tridion. I did not understand what does it mean. Can you please be little brief?

Comment: I've added some additional information to the answer for you.

Comment: I am using database.

Comment: I found the problem. The JDBC driver is missing in the filesystem. when i put that file there, i got it running. and the cd_dynamic configuration file is also missing with some information. Finally i got it running. Thanks for everyone who helped me with this.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the Tridion CM Explorer, find the publication you're publishing from and note its ID (tcm:0-x-1).

Now go to your website root, edit /bin/config/cd_dynamic_conf.xml. You'll find a node with a publication Id=y. Replace y with x. Do an iisreset.

Comment: I am using the correct publication ID

Answer (score 2):

I faced similar issue when license was missing or incorrect. Please re-validate your license's location, expiry in your reference implementation website.

Comment: License works fine.

Comment: if license correctly configured in cd_link_conf and cd_storage_conf, and other validation mentioned by Nuno and david. then Please check all system pages under _system SG are published? try publishing one by one.

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem. The JDBC driver is missing in the filesystem. when i put that file there, i got it running. and the cd_dynamic configuration file is also missing with some information. Finally i got it running. Thanks for everyone who helped me with this.

Answer (score 0):

This problem might also occur if your IIS application pool user does not have sufficient rights to write files in the BinaryData folder.

When first starting your website, the site loads a number of configuration files from the database, and writes them as files in the binarydata folder (for performance reasons).

If the user under which your application pool for the DXA website runs has no rights to write these files, you might see a similar error message.

Comment: I don't even have "Binarydata" folder in the root folder. How can i check if i have configurations in database. do they have any specific database or table?

Comment: I believe the BinaryData folder is created automatically when the first loads first. This does look like a write permissions issue. Can you change the user of the IIS Apppool for your DXA site to a user that has write rights in the website folder? The config files are published as binary json files, so you can check the binaries table to check if they are there.